# casting interface{} to string array

Tags: go

I'm trying to get the data which is stored in interface[] back to string array. Encountering an unexpected error.

```
type Foo struct {
    Data interface{}
}

func (foo Foo) GetData() interface{} {
    return foo.Data
}

func (foo *Foo) SetData(data interface{}) {
    foo.Data = data
}

func main() {
    f := &Foo{}
    f.SetData( []string{"a", "b", "c"} )

    var data []string = ([]string) f.GetData()
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

Error: main.go:23: syntax error: unexpected f at end of statement

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Luw08eiykJ)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What you are trying to perform is a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). There are specific rules for type conversions, all of which can be seen in the previous link. In short, you cannot convert an `interface{}` value to a `[]string`.

What you must do instead is a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), which is a mechanism that allows you to (attempt to) "convert" an interface type to another type:

```
var data []string = f.GetData().([]string)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/FRhJGPgD2z

Comment: thanks for clarification, I've a question, why people or down voting, do they expect I should know this before putting up a question or what?